# 1D Smooth Noise Function with Seed

Tags: java, noise, perlin-noise, random-seed

I cannot for the life of me find a java implementation of 1-dimensional noise with a seed.

I don't even need it to be Perlin/Simplex noise, I just need a simple and fairly smooth noise function. I hate to beg for source code, but I cannot find a good tutorial to write my own noise function because I'm an absolute dunce when it comes to mathematics.

```
public class Noise {

   int seed;

   public Noise(int seed) {
       this.seed = seed;
   }

   public float noise(float x) {
       // ???
   }
}
```

Comment: so... the Math.random() function, but then seeded? That'd be the [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, just build an instance and off you go.

Comment: That would be sufficient except I need it to be smoother than what java's Random offers.